# Filtering within an "inner value" in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, it's possible to sort by an "inner value", for example:

[image]

Is it also possible to do this in the "Filter" (more accurate, this would be a "having" clause), or is this option only available for sorting?

Here's a copy of an example sheet where I have the data sorted, and I'd also like to do a similar filter: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nfdh93lFcTHQQYB79mXGtz9huvJhvSfqTAw8GMMuEFU/edit#gid=0

Comment: @player0 updated with link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A:D, 
 "select A,sum(C) where C >= 2 group by A pivot B"), 
 "where Col2 is not null")
```

[image: 0]

---

**to mimic those Grand Totals from Pivot table:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{QUERY(QUERY(A:D, 
 "select A,sum(C) where C >= 2 group by A pivot B"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"),{"Grand Total"; 
 MMULT(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A:D, 
 "select sum(C) where C >= 2 group by A pivot B"), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "offset 1", 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)))^0)}};{"Grand Total", 
 TRANSPOSE(MMULT(transpose({QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A:D, 
 "select sum(C) where C >= 2 group by A pivot B"), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "offset 1", 0),
 MMULT(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A:D, 
 "select sum(C) where C >= 2 group by A pivot B"), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "offset 1", 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)))^0)}), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTUNIQUE(B2:B)))^0))}})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Very neat approach. So my guess is there isn't a way to do this directly in the pivot table itself?

Comment: pivot tables are very limited at this age

Comment: @David542 added variation if you need those grand totals